# How to make a style/color skin default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have style chooser on my [site](http://www.nanoinformaticseducation.com/). I can choose whatever style/color skin, using the gear located on the right-side. I am trying to figure out, How can I override the default style?

Comment: have javascript import a different stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch the CSS that is loaded by default quite easily. Do the following...

Open your `index.html` and on line #91 you will find the list of all the style sheets as shown below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/red.css" title="red" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/jade.css" title="jade" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/green.css" title="green" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/blue.css" title="blue" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/cyan.css" title="cyan" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/orange.css" title="orange" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/peach.css" title="peach" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/pink.css" title="pink" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/purple.css" title="purple" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/sky-blue.css" title="sky-blue" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/yellow.css" title="yellow" media="screen" />
```

The default style that is loaded is the first one at the top of the list, in this case it is `red.css`. So if you want to change the color for example lets say you want BLUE to be your default color scheme, you need to move `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/blue.css" title="blue" media="screen" />` to the top on line #91 or above the `red.css` to make it your default. You will need to make this change to all of your pages html files i.e `about.html`, `contact.html`, and so on.

If you've found it helpful please mark this as the accepted answer to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Nice answer, you seem really excited about imaginary internet points.